# Question in obfuscated code

Tags: discussion, mathjax, specific-question, etiquette

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861374/proof-verification-uniqueness-of-vector-v-satisfying-varphiu-langle-u) ([source (code) of second revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3f872b8c-5516-4095-9abd-e4647b35cee2/view-source)) is written in bizarre obfuscated code. I am referring to the code, ***not*** to what you see when you read the question. One cannot help suspect some kind of sarcasm on the part of the poster.  Should this be condoned?

Here is the code:

```
$\def\p{\varphi}\def\l{\langle}\def\r{\rangle}\def\v{v_1}\def\w{v_2}
\def\a{ \l u,v \r}\def\q{\p(u)}\def\b{\q = \a}\def\c{\l u, \v \r}
\def\d{\l u, \w \r}\def\e{\q=\c=\d}\def\f{\v-\w}\def\g{u=\f}
\def\h{0 = \c - \d = \l u , \f \r}\def\i{\f=0}\def\j{\v = \w}$
```

This was placed into the middle of a sentence written in English, interrupting it.  It is intended to produce this result:
$$
\varphi(u) = \langle u,v\rangle
$$

Comment: Looks like good ol' plainTeX macro definitions. The poster prefers to write `\p` in place of `\varphi` et cetera, and first defines the needed macros. I used those a lot before I was forced to switch to LaTeX. I bet that the macro definitions were copy/pasted from a private source.

Comment: But they're interspersed with the sentence written out in English and with each other in a way apparently intended to make the whole thing illegible.

Comment: Here's the code: \def\p{\varphi}\def\l{\langle}\def\r{\rangle}\def\v{v_1}\def\w{v_2}\def\a{ \l u,v \r}\def\q{\p(u)}\def\b{\q = \a}\def\c{\l u, \v \r}\def\d{\l u, \w \r}\def\e{\q=\c=\d}\def\f{\v-\w}\def\g{u=\f}\def\h{0 = \c - \d = \l u , \f \r}\def\i{\f=0}\def\j{\v = \w} ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You can define plainTeX-macros as you need them. No need to collect them to a preamble or such. Much like C-variables (as opposed readable programming languages like Pascal) - if you notice that you need one, you declare it then and there.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that the code I pasted above, which appeared in the middle of a sentence written in English, does not amount to obfuscation?  It was intended to produce this result: $\varphi(u)=\langle u,v\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You should see the plainTeX source to my dissertation, or better yet the source to missus physics (undergrad) thesis. She asked for the strangest things. Mind you, I think you have a point - that is IMVHO BAD TeX. But what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that if people post like this then others will have difficulty doing emendations to their post.

Comment: It does produce a lot else, too. Did you notice how the macros are used later in the text?

Comment: I didn't look at it that closely, and I shouldn't have to. The fact that you have to look at it closely in order to see things like that is one of the reasons to object to people writing like that.

Comment: I have sympathy for your cause, but I also have sympathy for that OP. It is IMHO **VERY ANNOYING** to have to write `\Bbb{Z}` a dozen times per post, when declaring `\def\Z{\Bbb{Z}}` once and then using `\Z'` ever after would do. This is how I still write my lecture notes, slides et cetera. Except that I need to use the LaTex-way with `\newcommand...`

Comment: But you can used things like \newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}, etc. I've done that. That can be done without anything that comes out looking like obfuscation.

Comment: "they're interspersed with the sentence written out in English" If you wrote them on a blank line cleanly separated from the English instead, it would produce a paragraph with no visible text, creating an unsightly gap in the output. I think you are too quick to assume malice.

Comment: @Jyrki: I think that in this specific case, the preamble is much more complicated than writing the code by hand each time it should appear.

Comment: Excuse me, but writing code like this is lunacy.  I can't believe someone is defending it.

Comment: Well, yeah. It is not exemplary use of macros, so the OP likely had other motives. Conceding that. But if it becomes "uneditable", why is that a problem? Looks like a pretty cleanly typeset question to me. I can't believe someone is upset about it.

Comment: In this particular instance I don't see a need to edit it, but it is bizarre and it's hard to believe someone would write like that if they didn't want their code to be incomprehensible.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the purpose of this question is. The code renders fine, and the question is quite readable; although this might be a case of poor coding practice, it certainly sounds like the poster is not alone in defining such macros. If it works well and renders quickly, why *should* one consider it to be "sarcasm," or have any opinion of it at all?

Comment: @T.Bongers Let's generalize here--don't worry about the specific case, but instead consider if this practice became widespread.  What happens if I need to edit an obfuscated question?  (e.g. a `}` is left out, and none of the code compiles)  TeX code should be written clearly because editors review the code, not just the output.

Comment: Furthermore, we can consider the consequences of using `\def` in the post.  For instance, $\def\p{\phi}$ if anyone types `$\p$` below this comment, it will be rendered as $\p$.  Doing this could cause conflicts with answers.

Comment: And simply editing out the obfuscating macros without raising a meta-thread wasn't an option because...?

Comment: Why need we assume malice over ignorance? Let us not forget that LaTeX is a relatively steep learning curve, especially when we start saying that you should use $\langle\cdot\rangle$ rather than $<\cdot>$. Copying in your favorite preamble and going from there is a tempting option to the novice.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I can imagine users being offended that their carefully crafted code is being completely changed by other users. I think that a general question about the appropriateness of carrying out pure (but quite large) code edits is worth discussing.

Comment: @T.Bongers Author's source code is still there in the revisions, as it was. The visible appearance of the post hasn't changed... Offended? I can imagine users being offended by pretty much anything. I can also imagine  harmful effects of not doing what is right for the fear of offending someone... As someone who frequently copies portions of code from question to answer, I find that having readable question sources to work with is quite useful. Also, the content of the posts is meant to be reusable elsewhere,  that's a part of the SE model.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Perhaps a user's misspelling of words is is a conscious and intentional choice. Or the inappropriate tagging of their questions. Or the lack of MathJax. Or a myriad of other things that many of us don't think twice about "correcting". IMHO, an important feature of the SE model is that [_users can edit others' posts_](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/editing). That a user might be "offended" by an edit that helps in the future maintenance (or readability, etc.) of a post without changing its content in any meaningful way is really among the least of my concerns.

Answer (score 7):

Although the post has been already brought into shape, for the future occasions I will point to [online macro-expander](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zoho/ed84y/show/light/) written by [Z.H. from TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153632).

For most posts, a single run of this script will suffice. But the post in question has triple-nested macros, which makes it necessary to run the script three times. For convenience, I moved the command with `\def` to the beginning of document (no preambles are needed, since the script does not actually parse TeX).

1. After the first run, first-level macros throughout the text   expanded, for example `$$\h$$` became `$$0 = \c - \d = \l u , \f \r$$`.
2. I copy-pasted the output  back into the input box, leaving the `\def` part as it were originally. Second run changed the above line to
   `$$0 = \l u, \v \r - \l u, \w \r = \langle u , \v-\w \rangle$$`
3. Rinse and repeat: 
   `$$0 = \langle u, v_1 \rangle - \langle u, v_2 \rangle = \langle u , v_1-v_2 \rangle$$`
4. Voilà, macros are gone.